# Unexpected backslash and line breaks in VS code integrated terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, zsh, git-bash, line-breaks, backslash

When using Git Bash (oh-my-zsh and p10k) from the VS Code integrated terminal I get a backslash in front of my prompt after pressing ENTER and I get an unexpected linebreak when there are p10k elements in the right of the prompt:

[VS code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7R46.png)

This problem does not occur in Windows Terminal:

[Windows terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wD9c7.png)

PLEASE HELP! This is driving me nuts.

Comment: does this happen if you disable oh-my-zsh and p10k?

Comment: There are literally two of us...  I have this too.  It came out of nowhere.  I can't figure out where it is coming from.  It happens even if oh-my-zsh is disabled.  I don't use p10k.

Comment: Same issure here. I followed [these instructions](https://dev.to/equiman/zsh-on-windows-without-wsl-4ah9) to install p10k. The issue arises as soon as I use ZSH in VSCode, disabling p10k does not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't add a comment under the question (not enough reputation), but there is a closed ticket on GitHub:

[There is a problem with VScode line wrapping #2348](https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k/issues/2348)

As romkatv stated on the issue, there is something wrong with rendering. At the moment, there isn't a way to fix the issue.